# SP2013 + Excel Services .. Help!

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, excel, excel-services

I've next scenarios, two server A and B, A is the server of front-end and B is the server of services, We have this in Internet, any users could select the information, this case de users anonymous, but present error in communication between server, always present when tried the select ay document in excel.

I was restarted, I changed the user of services of excel services, I was validated all users... Nothing

Help, please... HELP!!

[image: Problem I've!!!]

Comment: if for reference that issue, is because you server A is http and your server B in https or viceversa, you need stabled how used to excel and services in the parametrization inicial, and more if you should had http (A) and http (B) could be for reference of sql server.